# Is TypeScript case sensitive?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, case-sensitive

If you have a TypeScript DTO class with this property in Angular 8:

```
private active: boolean= true;

public get Active(): boolean {
    return this.active;
}

public set Active(pActive: boolean) {
    this.active= pActive;
}
```

In Angular input form, what should I use to bind this property to a checkbox, capital or not:
    `active = this.cbActive` or
    `Active = this.cbActive`
.. or I can use both?

Comment: No, it's case sensitive. `cbActive !== cbactive`. Generally, methods and properties in JS/TS are camelCase, not PascalCase.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript compiles to regular javascript. Because javascript is case sensitive, so does typescript. After all, typescript won't compile the variable to both active and Active.

Comment: So, if my property is `Active` in my dto class, I should use capital in input form and vice-versa?

Comment: If you can't change the names, yes. But as Phix replied, generally you should use camelCase for both the methods (functions) and properties, and PascalCase only for classes. Maybe rename `active` to `_active` and the getter and setter to `active`, but you not make the property public and remove the getter and setter?